# Displaying a custom field on view orders pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I figured how to display a value in order emails but I can't figure out how to display on order pages. Specifically, I'm displaying a link to author's profile who submitted a checkout form. This is to display a link value in emails:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 ); 

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) { 
    $fields['_user_link'] = array( 
        'label' => __( 'User Link' ), 
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_user_link', true ), 
    ); 
    return $fields; 
}
```

How can I show this link on order pages in Woocommerce?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update** — Make the link clickable:

Displaying your custom clickable link (your custom field) after order table:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'custom_order_details_after_order_table', 10, 1 );
function custom_order_details_after_order_table( $order ) {

    $user_link = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_user_link', true );

    echo '<p><a class="author-link" href="'. $user_link .'">'. __( 'User Link: ' ) . '</a><p>';

}
```

Displaying your custom field in Admin Orders view:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $user_link = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_user_link', true );
    if ( ! empty( $user_link ) )
        echo '<p>' . __( 'User Link: ' ) . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_user_link', true ) . '</p>';

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and working

Comment: This is working but how to actually make a hyperlink on the front end order page? To be clickable? Right now it's only outputting a text.